# Set theory and function composition

Tags: functions

$$f = \{  \langle 1,1 \rangle , \langle 2,3 \rangle , \langle 3,2 \rangle \} $$

What does the following composite mean:
$$f \circ f$$

Comment: Please use `\langle…\rangle` for $\langle…\rangle$. I fixed it for you this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of the pairs in $f$ of being of the form $\langle x, f(x) \rangle$, where $x$ ranges over the domain of $f$. So here, the domain of $f$ is $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$, and you're told that $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=3$ and $f(3)=2$.

So the domain of $f \circ f$ will also be $\{ 1, 2, 3 \}$. What is $(f \circ f) (1)$? What is $(f \circ f)(2)$? What is $(f \circ f)(3)$?

When you know this information you can then write
$$f \circ f = \{ \langle 1, (f \circ f) (1) \rangle, \langle 2, (f \circ f) (2) \rangle, \langle 3, (f \circ f) (3) \rangle \}$$

Comment: Got it! thanks sir

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\langle 1, 1 \rangle \in f$ is the definition for what we usually write as $f(1) = 1$. Hence

$$f \circ f(1) = f(f(1)) = f(1) = 1$$

so that $\langle 1, 1 \rangle \in f \circ f$. Now repeat for the other two possible input values; you should find that $f \circ f = \operatorname{Id}$.